# submit a form and prevent from refreshing it

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

i'm working on a email sending function on a project. here when i fill the form and after sending it the web site page getting refresh and showing white background page. i need to prevent that from the refreshing and submit the form. here i'l attach the codes and can someone tell me the answer for this question.

HTML code for form

```
<form class="form-vertical" onsubmit="return sendEmail();" id="tell_a_friend_form" method="post" action="index.php?route=product/product/tellaFriendEmail" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group ">
     <label class="control-label  ">Your Name <span >*  </span> </label><br>
       <div class="form-group-default">
         <input type="text" id="senders_name" name="sender_name" value="" class="form-control input-lg required" >
       </div>
    </div>

    <div id="notify2" class="">
      <div id="notification-text2" class="xs-m-t-10 fs-12"></div>
      <!--<button type="button" class ="close" id="noti-hide">×</button>-->
      </div>


      <div class="form-group ">
       <label class="control-label  ">Your Email <span >*  </span> </label><br>
         <div class="form-group-default">
           <input type="text" id="sender_email_ID" name="sender_email" value="" class="form-control input-lg" >
         </div>
       </div>

       <div id="notify1" class="">
         <div id="notification-text1" class="xs-m-t-10 fs-12"></div>
           <!--<button type="button" class ="close" id="noti-hide">×</button>-->
           </div>

           <div class="form-group ">
             <label class="control-label">Your Friends' Email <span >* </span></label>
               <p class="lineStyle">Enter one or more email addresses, separated by a comma.</p>

          <div class="form-group-default">
             <input type="text" value="" id="receiver_email" class="form-control required" name="receivers_email" >
             </div>
           </div>

           <div id="notify" class="">
             <div id="notification-text" class="xs-m-t-10 fs-12"></div>
               <!--<button type="button" class ="close" id="noti-hide">×</button>-->
              </div>

            <div >
              <label domainsclass="control-label ">Add a personal message below (Optional) <br></label>
                 <div class="form-group-default">
                   <textarea type="text" id="tell_a_friend_message" name="tell_a_friend_message" class="form-control" rows="10" col="100" style=" width: 330px; height: 100px;"></textarea>
                  </div>
               </div>

               <div id="notify3" class="">
                 <div id="notification-text3" class="xs-m-t-10 fs-12"></div>
                  <!--<button type="button" class ="close" id="noti-hide">×</button>-->
               </div>

               <input type="hidden" name="product_url" id="product_url_field" value="">

               <div class="p-t-15 p-b-20 pull-right">
                 <button id="send_mail_button" class="btn btn-rounded btn-rounded-fl-gold text-uppercase" name="submit" onclick="return sendEmail();" >Send</button>
                  <button id="cancel_email_form" class="btn btn-rounded btn-rounded-gold text-uppercase btn-margin-left" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" >Cancel</button>

                </div>
```

javascript code:

```
<script>

    function sendEmail() {

        document.getElementById('product_url_field').value = window.location.href
        var emailpattern = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
        var receivers_email = $("#receiver_email").val();
        var sender_email    = $("#sender_email_ID").val();
        var sender_name     = $("#senders_name").val();
        var email_pathname    = window.location.pathname;
        var product_url       = window.location.href;


        if (receivers_email == '') {

                $('#notify').removeClass().addClass("alert-danger");
                $('#notification-text').empty().html("Invalid e-mail or fill the email address correctly");
                $('#notification-text').show();
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $('#notification-text').fadeOut('slow');
                }, 10000);
                return false;

             }
             else {
                 !emailpattern.test(receivers_email);
                  }

        if(sender_name == ''){

            $('#notify2').removeClass().addClass("alert-danger");
            $('#notification-text2').empty().html("please fill the name");
            $('#notification-text2').show();
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('#notification-text2').fadeOut('slow');
            }, 10000);
            return false;
        }


        if (sender_email == '') {

                $('#notify1').removeClass().addClass("alert-danger");
                $('#notification-text1').empty().html("Invalid e-mail or fill the email address correctly");
                $('#notification-text1').show();
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $('#notification-text1').fadeOut('slow');
                }, 10000);
                return false;

         }
        else {
            !emailpattern.test(sender_email);

        }
        $('#notify3').removeClass().addClass("alert-success");
        $('#sender_email').val('');
        $('#notification-text3').empty().html("Email has sent successfully");
        $('#notification-text3').show();
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#notification-text3').fadeOut('slow');
        }, 10000);
        return true;
    }




</script>
```

Controller php class:

```
 public function tellaFriendEmail(){


        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

            $receiver_email = $_POST['receivers_email'];
            $name = $_POST['sender_name'];
            $email = $_POST['sender_email'];
            $message = $_POST['tell_a_friend_message'];
            $products_url = $_POST['product_url'];



            $mail = new Mail();
            $mail->protocol = $this->config->get('config_mail_protocol');
            $mail->parameter = $this->config->get('config_mail_parameter');
            $mail->smtp_hostname = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_hostname');
            $mail->smtp_username = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_username');
            $mail->smtp_password = html_entity_decode($this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_password'), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
            $mail->smtp_port = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_port');
            $mail->smtp_timeout = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_timeout');
            $mail->setTo($receiver_email);

            $mail->setFrom($this->config->get('config_email'));
            $mail->setSender("Waltersbay");
            $mail->setSubject($name.' '.'wants you to checkout this product from waltersbay.com');

                    if ($message !=''){
                        $mail->setHtml('Hi Dear,<br/> please checkout the following product that'.' '.$name.' '.'wanted you to see.'.' '.'we hope that you will like it !!!!<br/>'.$products_url.'<br/>'.'<br/> Here is a little message from your friend:<br/>'.$message.'<br/>'.'<br/> Thank you, <br/>  ');
                    }
                      else{
                        $mail->setHtml('Hi Dear,<br/> please checkout the following product that'.' '.$name.' '.'wanted you to see.'.' '.'we hope that you will like it !!!!<br/>'.$products_url.'<br/>'/*.'<br/> Here is a little message from your friend:<br/>'.$message.'<br/>'*/.'<br/> Thank you, <br/>  ');
                      }
            $mail->send();





        }
        else{
            header('location : tella_friend.tpl');


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure if I understood the problem, but I think redirecting to a different page upon successful operation should solve your refresh problem (i.e. even if the user hits refresh on the redirected page, the email sending script won't run a second time)

Answer (score 0):

Put a hidden input in your form. before submitting in your js, fill it with a new key according to time.

in your php file check if key is duplicate or not? or even if its filled?

Because js fill this input after clicking the submit button, every time you submit your form you have a new key! If you refresh the form, you're gonna send the previous value again.

Answer (score 0):

For your problem then best practice recommended is to use jquery ajax requests.

Firstly if you pretend to use "submit" element then do following,

```
$(".form-vertical").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //send ajax with your form data. Ample examples on SO already.
    $.ajax(.....);
});
```

Other option we would recommend is to avoid using 'submit' behavior at first place for requirement you have.

```
 1. Use button elements instead of submit element.
 2. Attach click event on button. i.e. in your case 'send'.
 3. On click, send ajax as described above. This will avoid doing things like onsubmit="return sendEmail();" you had to do. 
 4. Also following is not required as well,
   $(".form-vertical").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
 as it will be done as follows,
   $("button#buttonId").click(function(e) {
    // your ajax call.....
   }
```